# why i get extra line in CAShapeLayer while adding layer to image view

Tags: objective-c, chat, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am using the following code, and I get an extra stroke line at the left top side in chat bubble. Please check this image for reference:
[image]

```
UIRectCorner corners;

if (type == BubbleTypeSomeoneElse)
{
    self.bubbleImage.image = nil;
    corners = UIRectCornerBottomRight|UIRectCornerTopRight|UIRectCornerTopLeft;
}
else {
    self.bubbleImage.image = nil;
    corners = UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight|UIRectCornerTopLeft;
}

// space between each bubble
self.bubbleImage.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width + self.data.insets.left + self.data.insets.right, height + self.data.insets.top-10 + self.data.insets.bottom);

UIBezierPath *path  = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bubbleImage.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7, 7)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bubbleImage.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = path.CGPath;

CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
borderLayer.frame = self.bubbleImage.bounds;
borderLayer.path  = path.CGPath;
borderLayer.lineWidth   = 1.0f;
borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

[self.bubbleImage.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in the above code, if need anything more from my code comment down I will provide as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have shown, there's no problem at all:

[image]

Therefore the problem is due to code you have *not* shown. But what that code is, is impossible to say, because, uh, you have not shown that code.

At a guess, however, I would suggest you consider this: Your code shows that you are making the image view's image `nil` each time your code runs. That's good. But your code does *not* remove the previous existing `layer` which you added the previous time this code ran. Therefore I'm betting that what you are seeing is left over from the previous existing `layer` which you forgot to remove.

Indeed, if this code runs multiple times there is a great danger of piling up sublayers on top of one another.

Comment: Hello @matt 

Thanks for your valuable response, By removing the previous layer solved my problem, I am using following code for removing sublayers

self.bubbleImage.layer.sublayers = nil;